# Querying file in memory

Tags: java, apache, file

I have a comma separated file, which I want to load into memory and query it as if it was a database, I've come across many concepts/names but am not sure which is correct  like ... embedded DB, in-memory database (Apache ignite, etc ...), how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to work with Apache Spark, you can load your file and then query it using spark-sql as follow:

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("csvfile.csv")
// Select only the "user_id" column
df.select("user_id").show()
```

see [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache Spark 1.6 version, your code would be

```
HiveContext hqlContext = new HiveContext(sparkContext);

        DataFrame df = hqlContext.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("inferSchema", "true")
                .option("header", "true").load(csvpath);
        df.registerTempTable("Table name");
```

And then you can query from the table